# SQL Server 2008 BULK INSERT DateTime Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert, bulk

I am trying to use BULK INSERT in SQL Server 2008 to import a TSV (Tab Separated Value) file.

Here is my script:

```
USE ABC
GO

CREATE TABLE CSVTest
(ID INT,
FirstName VARCHAR(40),
LastName VARCHAR(40),
TodaysDate DATETIME)
GO

BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'd:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO

--Check the content of the table.
SELECT *
FROM CSVTest
GO

--Drop the table to clean up database.
SELECT *
FROM CSVTest
GO

DROP TABLE CSVTest
GO
```

Here is the content of the file `d:\csvtest.txt`:

```
1   James   Smith   16/10/2010 04:45:35
2   Meggie  Smith   16/10/2010 04:45:35
3   Robert  Smith   16/10/2010 04:45:35
4   Alex    Smith   16/10/2010 04:45:35
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 4 (TodaysDate).

Obviously, I need to convert the date format in my TSV file to a format that is acceptable to `DATETIME`.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: If you post code, you should really use the Code Format button (the little button with the '101 010' picture)... it makes your question much easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am wondering if this has to do with it expecting months first, and not days in your date format of 16/10/2010 (i.e., it expects 10/16/2010). You can try doing this before the BULK INSERT:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
```